# How to pass "y" to pscp process started with PowerShell Start-Process?

Tags: powershell, ssh, ssh-keys, start-process, pscp

I would like to `pscp` some files from Windows to Linux server. The following code (PowerShell) is what I was trying. It worked fine, but I need to input <kbd>y</kbd>, when it's trying to communicate with remote server, cause the hostname is unknown for Windows.

```
$proc = Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credential -ArgumentList "Start-Process C:\pscp.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-i C:\prikey.ppk D:\temp\* corey@11.22.33.44:/home/corey/' -Wait" -PassThru
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

It will show something like this:

> The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You have no
>   guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is. The
>   server's ssh key fingerprint is: xxxxxx If you trust this host, enter
>   "y" to add the key to PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting......
>   Store key in cache? (y/n)

Is there any way to `echo "y"` automatically (non-interactive) while using `Start-Process`? Or disable Windows's SSH host checking (even better for me)?

Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to blindly answer "y" to `pscp` host key verification prompt. You lose a protection against [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

You should use the [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey) with your host key fingerprint.

---

A host key is part of the information you should have about any SSH server, along with the credentials. – Though as a compromise, you may want to implement an equivalent of OpenSSH `accept-new` mode. For an example, see WinSCP article [Implementing SSH host key cache (known hosts)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_known_hosts). – If you use `"MD5"` instead of `"SHA-256"`, you will get the fingerprint almost in the format needed for `pscp`.